# Pushing '~' gives me '=' character with the keyboard of Toshiba Dynabook Satellite J50

Tags: keyboard, toshiba-laptop

I have Toshiba Dynabook Satellite J50 laptop. It seems that something is wrong with the keyboard. For example, When I press the <kbd>~</kbd> key, <kbd>=</kbd> comes out. But the <kbd>=</kbd> is on another key which is adjacent to the <kbd>~</kbd> key.

Has anyone else had this issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: Is it just those 2 keys?

Comment: Several keys on the right part of the keyboard.

Comment: I don't know how to input the tilde sign(~) and at sign(@) with the keyboard.